# Find all possible sums of a rows of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Specifically, I have a generator matrix
$$G=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&1&1 \\
0&1&0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and I must find all 16 codewords that are in this code. I am told this can be done by taking all possible sums of the rows of *G*, but I am struggling on how.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, and I am afraid that some users believe it should [get closed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates). To prevent that, please tell us (in the question body) what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a binary linear code with generator the matrix you mentioned. In order to find explicitly the code we have to multiply the generator with all the vectors $[a,b,c,d]$, where $a,b,c,d$ are $0$ or $1$. The last means that all the words should be of the form $ae_1+be_2+ce_3+de_4$, where $e_i$ are the rows of the matrix.